Is my proof for the additivity of the limit correct?
I am working with the following question, and would like to use the non-standard definition of the limit found in Keislers Calculus an infinitesimal approach:

Suppose $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$, for some $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ . Prove that if $\lim_{x \to a} f\left(x\right)=L$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g\left(x\right)=M$, then $\lim_{x \to a} \left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)=L+M$

The non-standard definition for the limit I would like to use is:

$\lim_{x\to a}f\left(x\right)=L \iff x\approx a \;\wedge\ x\not=a  \implies f\approx L$

So what I have to prove is that $\forall x\in {}^*U. x\approx  a$ and $x\not=a \implies {}^*f+{}^*g\approx L+M$, where $q\approx p$ if and only if $q-p$ is infinitesimal or zero. Now for the proof (or my attempt at one):

Let $x\approx a$ and $x\not=a$. By the two given limits, we know that ${}^*f\approx L$ and ${}^*g\approx M$. This implies that ${}^*f+{}^*g\approx L+M$. This means that $x\approx a$ and $x\not=a$ $\implies {}^*f+{}^*g\approx L+M$. This is equivalent to saying $\lim_{x \to a} \left(f\left(x\right)+g\left(x\right)\right)=L+M$, which completes the proof.

Is my proof correct? Have I made any mistakes or have I missed something? Thank you in advance!

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

When you write ${}^\ast\! f\approx L$ (and other similar formulas) it looks a little odd.  Try to replace them by ${}^\ast\! f(x)\approx L$ (of course if $x\approx a$ and $x\not=a$) and the like.  The key step is that if $y\approx L$ and $z\approx M$ then $y+z \approx L+M$.    If you need this for homework, you should make sure that you are allowed to use such an inference.

If I were not allowed to make such an inference, would it be okay to state that since $^{}f(x) \approx L$, then $f(x) = L+\alpha_1$, for some infinitesimal $\alpha_1$. Then one does the same thing for $^{}g(x)$ and uses the properties of the "="-relation to conclude $^{}g(x)+^{}f(x) = L+M+\alpha_1+\alpha_2$, which means $^{}g(x)+^{}f(x) \approx L+M$?

Fine, provided one knows that infinitesimals are closed under addition :-)  Incidentally, you should use the "!" command to reduce space between the star on the left and the function symbol it is attached to.
